# Remove duplicate words in strings in column in every row in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove duplicate words in strings in my data frame per row.

Say my data frame looks like this:

```
In:
Yes Yes Absolutely
No No Nope   
Win Win Lose



  for row in df.iterrows():
        row["Sentence"] = (list(set(row["Sentence"])))

Desired Out:
Yes Absolutely
No Nope
Win Lose
```

How can I clean, each row to remove the duplicate strings. I have tried the above code.

Any links to any docs or sources would be greatly appreciated if they can lead me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (assuming column name is 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
df[0].str.split().apply(lambda x: ','.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()))

0    Yes,Absolutely
1           No,Nope
2          Win,Lose
```

Note , you can use set as:

```
df[0].str.split().apply(lambda x: ','.join(list(set(x))))
```

But set doesn't guarantee the order.

Comment: It says 7 minutes to accept an answer, I will give it a click when the times up!